# Gradle zip task fails because zip does not exist

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle build script which contains a task that is something like the following:

```
task unzip_foo_bar (type: Copy) {
    from zipTree ("foo.zip").matching { include '**/bar.h' }.singleFile
    into "build"
}
```

The .zip file gets fetched from an external repository into the local workspace before the task is executed.

But for some reason, when you use .matching along with .singleFile, Gradle expects the zip file to already be present in the local workspace when the script is compiled.

In this case, the script compilation fails due to the fact that the .zip file does not exist at compile time.

So the following works without issue:

```
task unzip_foo_bar (type: Copy) {
    from zipTree ("foo.zip")
    into "build"
}
```

In this case, Gradle is able to compile the script and it just works.

Can someone explain the difference in behavior?

The reason for the first implementation is that I would like to be able to extract a single file from the .zip archive instead of dumping all the files from the archive into the local workspace.

How would I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `zipTree` in Gradle returns a `FileTree`, which supports lazy evaluation, so that the contents of the tree are determined only when needed. Various task types like the `Copy` task support this behavior by allowing the user to pass a tree as an input. The tree can be constructed during *configuration phase*, but it is only queried during *execution phase* if and when the task is executed.

Now the problem with your first example is that calling `singleFile` triggers the tree evaluation, because it needs to return an instance of `File`. To find that file, Gradle needs to open the `.zip` file and fails because the file cannot be found. The `matching` call is not the problem, because it creates another lazy-evaluated `FileTree`. So just drop the call to `singleFile` and your code should work:

```
from zipTree ("foo.zip").matching { include '**/bar.h' }
```

However, if you want to keep the assertion that just a single file matches the pattern, you can wrap your expression in a `Closure` that will be evaluated lazily as a whole:

```
from { zipTree ("foo.zip").matching { include '**/bar.h' }.singleFile }
```